# Oracle - Inner query takes time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries:

```
select * from PRE_DETAIL_REPORT a where item = (select item from apple_skus);
select * from PRE_DETAIL_REPORT a where item IN ('100299122');
```

the table: `APPLE_SKUS`
only has one item: **100299122**

When I run the first query, it takes 2 minutes to execute
When I run the second query, it takes 3 seconds to execute

What can be the reason?

Comment: Query 1 also has to read the apple_skus table.

Comment: the table only has one row

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Compare the execution plans.

Comment: run explain plan on both and post the results

Comment: Is `PRE_DETAIL_REPORT` a view? Is `APPLE_SKUS` a table that used to be large but was deleted down to one row - sometimes a single row may take up a lot of space on disk if that space wasn't reclaimed. Run this query to see how many megabytes of disk space are used to store that one row of data: `select bytes/1024/1024 mb from dba_segments where segment_name = 'APPLE_SKUS';`
For generating the explain plans, run `explain plan for select ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)`, for both queries, and then edit the question with the plans.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite it in this way:

```
select a.* from PRE_DETAIL_REPORT a 
join apple_skus t on t.item = a.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the way a sql query syntax works

You have manual values for selection in your 2nd query but in the first case you have subquery specified so again a

FROM CLAUSE, N THEN SELECT so, Querying a table will take
more time than a hardcode value  even when theres a single record

You could try EXISTS as it uses correlated subquery which would be much faster

```
    Select * from table  t1 where exists (select  1 from table 
    where 
     Item =t1.item)
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s very likely that the difference is due to a different access to PRE_DETAIL_REPORT; and as mentioned earlier by someone, an explain plan (or SQL Monitor report) will tell you the answer.
But until you provide the diagnostic, this is just a guess…